# compare large sets of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, combinations

I have a numpy array A of n 1x3 arrays where n is the total number of possible combinations of elements in the 1x3 arrays, where each element ranges from 0 to 50. That is,

```
 A = [[0,0,0],[0,0,1]...[0,1,0]...[50,50,50]]
```

and

```
 len(A) = 50*50*50 = 125000
```

I have a numpy array B of m 1x3 arrays where m = 10 million, and the arrays can have values belonging to the set described by A.

I want to count up how many of each combination is present in B, that is, how many times `[0,0,0]` appears in B, how many times `[0,0,1]` appears...how many times `[50,50,50]` appears. So far I have the following:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
   for j in range(len(B)):
    if np.array_equal(A[i], B[j]):
        y[i] += 1
```

where y keeps track of how many times the ith array occurs. So, `y[0]` is how many times `[0,0,0]` appeared in B, `y[1]` is how many times `[0,0,1]` appeared...`y[125000]` is how many times `[50,50,50]` appeared, etc.

The problem is this takes forever. It has to check 10 million entries, 125000 times. Is there a quicker and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Just a little nitpick: `0, ..., 50` are 51 numbers, so len(A) would be `51^3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `dict()` to speed up this process to just going through 10 million entries.

So the first thing you want to do is to change all the sublists in A to hashable objects do you can use them as keys in a dict.

Converting all the sublists to tuples:

```
A = [tuple(i) for i in A]
```

Then create a `dict()` with every value in A as the key and the value being 0.

```
d = {i:0 for i in A}
```

Now for each subarray in your numpy array, you just want to convert it to a tuple and increment d[that array] by 1

```
for subarray in B:
    d[tuple(subarray)] += 1
```

D is now a dictionary where for each key the value is how many times that key occured in B.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fast approach. It processes `10` million tuples out of `range(50)^3` in a fraction of a second and is roughly `100` times faster than the next best solution (@Primusa's):

It uses the fact that there is a straight-forward translation between such tuples and the numbers `0 - 50^3 - 1`. (The mapping happens to be the same as the one between the rows of your `A` and the row numbers.) The functions `np.ravel_multi_index` and `np.unravel_index` implement this translation and its inverse.

Once `B` is translated into numbers, their frequencies can be determined very efficiently using `np.bincount`. Below I reshape the result to get a `50x50x50` histogram but that is just a matter of taste and can be left out. (I have taken the liberty to only use numbers `0` through `49`, so `len(A)` becomes `125000`):

```
>>> B = np.random.randint(0, 50, (10000000, 3))
>>> Br = np.ravel_multi_index(B.T, (50, 50, 50))
>>> result = np.bincount(Br, minlength=125000).reshape(50, 50, 50)
```

Let's look at a smaller example for demonstration:

```
>>> B = np.random.randint(0, 3, (10, 3))
>>> Br = np.ravel_multi_index(B.T, (3, 3, 3))
>>> result = np.bincount(Br, minlength=27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
>>> 
>>> B
array([[1, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 2],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0]])
>>> result
array([[[0, 0, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[2, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

To query for example how many times `[2,1,0]` is in B one would do

```
>>> result[2,1,0]
1
```

As mentioned above: To convert between indices into your `A` and the actual rows of `A` (which are the indices into my `result`), `np.ravel_multi_index` and `np.unravel_index` can be used. Or you can leave out the last reshape (i.e. use `result = np.bincount(Br, minlength=125000)`; then the counts are indexed exactly the same as `A`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the unique rows and their counts from array `B` by calling the `np.unique` over its first axis and `return_counts=True`. Then, you can use broadcasting to find the indices of the `B`'s unique rows in `A` by calling the `ndarray.all` and `ndarray.any` methods on proper axises. Then all you need is just a simple indexing:

```
In [82]: unique, counts = np.unique(B, axis=0, return_counts=True)

In [83]: indices = np.where((unique == A[:,None,:]).all(axis=2).any(axis=0))[0]

# Get items from A that exist in B
In [84]: unique[indices]

# Get the counts 
In [85]: counts[indices]
```

Example:

```
In [86]: arr = np.array([[2 ,3, 4], [5, 6, 0], [2, 3, 4], [1, 0, 4], [3, 3, 3], [5, 6, 0], [2, 3, 4]])

In [87]: a = np.array([[2, 3, 4], [1, 9, 5], [3, 3, 3]])

In [88]: unique, counts = np.unique(arr, axis=0, return_counts=True)

In [89]: indices = np.where((unique == a[:,None,:]).all(axis=2).any(axis=0))[0]

In [90]: unique[indices]
Out[90]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [3, 3, 3]])

In [91]: counts[indices]
Out[91]: array([3, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
y=[np.where(np.all(B==arr,axis=1))[0].shape[0] for arr in A]
```

`arr` just iterate over `A` and `np.all` checks where it matches with `B` and `np.where` returns the positions of those matches as an array then `shape` just returns the length of that array or in other words the desired frequency